# What is the difference in pronunciation of the letters E and I?

Tags: pronunciation

I watched a few videos on the German alphabet, like these two: [1](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e6vquyjxImk), [2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BlYLQvtG1as).

It seems that the difference between *E* and *I* is very subtle – both sound like the English *ee* to me. How do I make sure I pronounce it correctly?

This question is about pronouncing the letters *E* and *I* themselves, outside words.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The English *ee*, as in *speech*, is the same sound as the German *I* [iː]. There is no exact equivalent to German *E* [eː] in the standard varieties of English (Received Pronunciation, General American).

The difference in pronunciation is the degree to which the jaw is opened; [e] is less open than [i]. The position of the tongue is the same for both vowels (this is in the front).

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't understand. Could you give a couple of examples for I and E? I feel like "neben" and "isst" are good examples on how to say E and I; am I right?

Comment: _Neben_ is fine; but _isst_ has a short i that in German is not only shorter, but slightly less open and less front as well. Examples with a long i: _sie_, _die_, _Biene_, _niedrig_.

Comment: @Oleksiy But only the first e in "neben". The latter one is either is omitted (nebn) or may sound almost like *ä* in some regions (nebän).

Comment: @Oleksiy There might be differences based on your dialect, but I believe the German "e" to sound like the expression "meh" while the German "i" sounds like "me".

Comment: In addition, in many regions the sound "ä" is more and more pronounced as an "e": ähnlich --> ehnlich, schräg --> schrehg etc.

Comment: @marsze: The letter _E_ is everywhere pronounced [eː], never [ɛː]. On the other hand, Em1 referred to a schwa [ə], as in _Biene_ [biːnə].

Comment: @chirlu Why do you tell me that? o_O I was talking about the German "ä" [ɛː] and said, that it is often pronounced rather as an "e" [eː].

Comment: @marsze: I understood you, but why were *you* saying that? It has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: @chirlu It was just an addition. If Oleksiy wants to know how to pronounce the letters "e" and "i" correctly, he can now have a look at the "ä" as well, because it is often pronounced similarly (that is, practically the same sound).

Comment: @chirlu This is wrong. Or how do you pronounce Herr? ;) (unless you're Bavarian and say [he:a])

Comment: @Jan: What is it that you think is wrong? – Personally, I pronounce _Herr_ as [hɛɐ̯], but I fail to see the connection to anything that was said above.

Comment: @chirlu 'The letter _E_ is everywhere pronounced [e:], never [ɛː].' In the context of how letters _in words_ are pronounced, it's wrong, because there are words in which _E_ is pronounced as [ɛ] (and the long/short distinction is weak in German).

Comment: @Jan: Of course, but the question was about letter names. To use another example that may make it more clear, _J_ is pronounced [ʝɔt], which does not mean that _ja_ would be pronounced [ʝɔtaː].

Answer (score 2):

This is only marginally an answer to your question, but if you are spelling out words and want to make sure not to be misunderstood, you can follow the *e* with an *Emil* and the *i* with *Isidor* or *Ida* from the spelling alphabet. Even if you pronounce it as *i*-ish as possible, nobody would assume *Imil* or *Eda*, because they’re just so used to the usual table.

The entire table can be found [on German Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buchstabiertafel#Geschichte).

Answer (score -2):

A = "ah"
E = "ay", unless at the end of a word, then it is "eh"
I = ""ee", as in see, unless at the beginning of a word, then it is a short "i", as in sit
O = "oh"
U = "ooo", as in hoot
Ä = "ay", with rounded lips
Ö = "er", with rounded lips
Ü = "ee", with rounded lips
AU = "ow"
AÜ = "oy"
EE = "ee", as in see
EI = "I", as in eye
EU = "oy"
IE = "ee", as in see

Comment: The answer doesn't match the question.

Answer (score -4):

**I** as ie in briefing, or ee in beef.

**E** as a in say, or hay.

Actually it's like E in latin: "**E**rrare humanum **e**st."
Or the Spanish **E** in **E**spagñol.

Comment: What is _breefing_? Do you mean _briefing_? The sounds in _say_, _Berber_, _Ethiopia_ are quite different (and some differ even between dialects of English), so they are not a good example for how something should be pronounced. Finally, it’s certainly not how _errare_ and _est_ were pronounced in classical Latin, and modern pronunciation again varies heavily between and even inside countries.

Comment: What do you know about classical pronounciation of latin? Even if they are different in various countries, in Latin each letter has an intrinsic value. Quite unlike English, where pronounciation and writing is specific to each word, and even to the context. [How do you pronounce the *i* "lives"? - It depends on the context (he lives, the lives)!]

Comment: Yeah, English is particularly horrible, but Latin is far from phonological spelling, too. In particular, the letter _e_ can stand for a short, more open or a long, more closed vowel; and it so happens that both in _errare_ and _est_, the _e_ is short (and hence open, similar to the German short _e_ or _ä_ in, e.g., _Fest_, of which we are **not** speaking here). In any case, referring to Latin words is not a useful pronunciation hint; [Latin regional pronunciation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_regional_pronunciation) on the English Wikipedia is an interesting read regarding this.