# Noob question about German pronunciation

Tags: pronunciation, spelling

Let me first give a big fat disclaimer that I essentially **know no German at all**. Being an IPA junkie I just decided to read about German orthography and (epicfailingly) try to read out some German for fun.

I have a problem with the long E (/e:/) sound. I hear it as /i:/ in some words and /e:/ in some words, but *nothing I can find supports this*. For example, by all spelling rules, and even by the pronunciation key in my dictionary, "Heer" and "hehr" are homophonous and pronounced [heːɐ̯].

Somehow, I hear "Heer" as [hiːɐ̯] and "hehr" as [heːɐ̯]. Google Translate's text-to-speech seems to support this.

So there seems to be a class of words where /e:/ gets pronounced /i:/ to my ears. Note that I cannot find anything online that supports that /e:/ ever turns into /i:/...

My (probably unreliable Chinese) ears hear [i:] in **LEben**, **MEmel**, **strEben**, etc. Dictionaries all agree on [e:], and no orthography description seems to mention `e` pronounced as [i:] anywhere.

I am fairly sure that this isn't just a mishearing. Is this a very recent sound change? Hitler (sorry, no better example) seems not to use it, but that might be because he is Austrian?

Comment: There is no `Austrian language` and `e` gets _never_ pronounced `i`. But `e` can make a long `i`: Bier, Tier, Liebe, Sieb, etc.

Comment: de.wiktionary.org uses a pronounciation which clearly uses /e:/. http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4f/De-Heer.ogg

Comment: Have you tried Forvo? http://de.forvo.com/search/lieben/ http://de.forvo.com/search/leben/

Comment: Can you provide a link to where you're hearing "Heer" pronounced as [hiːɐ̯]? I think that would be really interesting. (Of course, it might just be a case of an over-eager English native speaker who's too confident about his German pronunciation... let's see)

Comment: Interestingly, just the wiktionary file that @Toscho sounds as /i:/ to me. I stretched out the vowel in the word and it seems to sound like /i:/ to me: https://soundcloud.com/eric-dong-1/iiiiiiiiiiiii

Comment: Also: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VhQwLeMcbRY&nofeather=True I clearly hear **Memel** as /mi:mel/ as if it were spelled **Miemel**.

Comment: @user54609 If there is no hard- or software failure concerned, you should accustom yourself to the fact, that this is /i:/. Compare http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a3/De-at-hier.ogg and http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4f/De-Heer.ogg

Comment: Lol, they sound so homophonous to my ears :( I guess that since I never spoke a language with actual /e:/ (I know Spanish, English, Chinese, Japanese), the highest "e-sound" I know about is /e̞/ and I hear everything higher than that as /i/ :(

Comment: @Toscho... that is by no means a clear /e:/. See my answer for more on that

Comment: @user54609 ... stretching and such things introduce a lot of artifacts and also they cloud the onset which is often crucial. A piano sounds like a piano because of the onset... the middle is just some arbitrary harmonic sound. Anyway, I do agree that there is "i" in there, too.

Comment: I've actually heard this pronunciation in the German broadway version of Circle of Life from the Lion King. However, it will probably only happen if the speaker stresses the letter very forcefully. It's kind of like how damn can be pronounced dayum in English (especially by Black Americans).

Comment: For what it's worth, this is by far not the only time this issue comes up here - cf. [*Problem differentiating between [i:] and [e:]*](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/20035); [*Warum das 'e' manchmal wie 'i' klingt*](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/69576/warum-das-e-manchmal-wie-i-klingt); [*What is the difference in pronunciation of the letters E and I?*](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7872); [*Wie kann man zwischen den Namen der Buchstaben "i" und "e" unterscheiden?*](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/58632) ...

Comment: ... every time this comes up, I (as a native German speaker) am baffled by the suggestion that 'e' and 'i' could be confused with one another, but given the frequency at which this claim is mentioned by native speakers of other languages, it seems at least some other languages do not train speakers to hear the difference.

Answer (score 6):

I think you might be reading (sorry, hearing) too much into this. As an (admittedly, Austrian) native speaker, "Heer" and "hehr" are perfect homophones. There should also be no [i:] in any of the other words you mention.

Answer (score 2):

/eː/ and /i:/ are quite different

- /eː/ as in **Leben**, **Heer** and **streben**
- /i:/ as in **lieben**, **hier**, and **Striemen**

The only I can think of is, that there is slightly more "breath" in *Heer* (and also *hehr* and *mehr*) in comparison to *Leben* and *Streben*, because of the ***h***.

Any other sources than Google text-to-speech?

Answer (score 2):

You're right about Google translate but their rendition of "heer" is flawed. It should sound exactly the same as "hehr".
Whether you want it or not, your brain will "top down" on your perception. What I mean by that is the following. You see a certain spelling and your brain associates a certain sound. If you see the spelling and hear the rendition the audio you expect kind of mixes with the audio you hear. Your brain has to categorize it somehow and the result is "i" because that's what the "ee" spelling usually sounds like in English, which is as I understand not your mother-tongue, yet, you're "at home" in the language.

If you want to find out, if there really is a difference, have a friend play back a trustworthy rendition (not Google, try Leo.org) to you at random without you seeing the spelling. I wouldn't be surprised if the difference is gone.

EDIT:

There is of course a variation in the realization of the sound so some renditions may be closer to "i" than others. Depends on the context and of course on the speaker.

That's where the top down process of the native speakers kicks in so even if someone tells you that it is a clear "e" that doesn't mean that it is. You'd need to compare spectra to objectively judge that.
All native speakers including me have read your question here and we're all thinking the same thing "There ain't no difference". But that is only because our brain "smoothes" out the one that might be there. You have to be really analytical to turn that off. Either way, I think there is no systematic deviation that would make "heer" different by default

Comment: English having ee as /i:/ doesn't explain why I hear **Leben** as almost homophonous to **Lieben**.

Comment: Also, Finnish ee is a very clear /e:/.

Comment: @user54609... why doesn't it? I mean, I am not saying that this explains it but it is a possibility and your dismissing it so quickly makes you no different than people that tell you that you hear "wrong". Ultimately to answer the question you'd need to make a spectral analysis of several renditions of "heer" and "hehr". Only then can you obtain an objective result for personal judgment will always be influenced by to down processes.

Comment: @user54609.. also, your question as I understood it was about a supposed difference between two German sounds. Whether or not the Finnish "e" is closer to the centroid of IPA doesn't matter at all

Comment: I understand what you mean. So if I speak German, and pronounce Leben as Lieben, I would be easily misunderstood, correct? What if I use a slightly lower /e/, more to the direction of ä?

Comment: @user54609... well, the context does a lot. If you were to say "Ich liebe meine Leben" I think you could get away with pronouncing both vowels the same way. People's brains would do the rest. A few friends and me we have taken on the habit of saying "Brust" (breast, chest) instead of "Prost"... just with a slightly harder "b" than usual. No one ever notices despite there being a difference in "b" vs. "p", vowel length AND vowel quality. The context blinds you to it in a way.

Comment: I am a German teacher and there are many people who have problems telling the difference between the light "e" and the short closed "i" (I think it's /I/ but I don't know IPA very well). THose two are really damn close, especially because they are both short. One other example is "wer" and "wir"... I could get by just using something in the middle all the time... . With one meaning "we" and the other being a question word (who) the context will always be clear.

Comment: @Emanuel: but there is a big difference between "ich liebe meine Lieben" (I love my beloved ones) and "ich liebe mein Leben" (I love my life). Not to consider "Ich lebe mein Leben" (I live my life). How do you expect to get away with an ambiguous pronounciation in that case? (Particularly if a wrong article mein/meine may be attributed to your difficulties as a forgein speaker?)

Comment: @cbeleites.. what I am saying is that I am quite certain that if I said "Ich l_be mein L_ben."... with a "i"ish "e" everyone would probably understand "Ich liebe mein Leben" as soon as there is a little context. The version with "meine" doesn't come into play at all since the rhythm is clearly different.