# Wie kann man zwischen den Namen der Buchstaben "i" und "e" unterscheiden?

Tags: pronunciation, letter

Gibt es überhaupt einen Unterschied in der Aussprache von dem Buchstabe "e" und dem Buchstabe "i"? Ich habe ja keinen gehört (in google translate).
Wie weiß man um welchen es sich handelt, wenn man den richtigen nur aus Zuhören erkennen soll?

Im Übrigen, auch zwischen "a" und "h" ist der Unterschied nicht immer sehr deutlich kann ich mir vorstellen..

** Ich möchte nochmals betonen, dass die Frage nur auf die Namen der Buchstaben bezieht, und nicht auf ihren Teil in einem Wort.

> **Diese Frage wurde auch hier (auf Englisch) beantwortet:**
>   *[Problem differentiating between [i:] and [e:]](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/20035/problem-differentiating-between-i-and-e)*
>   *[What is the difference in pronunciation of the letters E and I?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7872/what-is-the-difference-in-pronunciation-of-the-letters-e-and-i)*

Comment: I'm sure there are [tons of videos on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wpBPaDI5IgI) about the matter. Also, check the [phonetic alphabet](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/German/Grammar/Alphabet_and_Pronunciation)

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to state your native language (and other languages you are intimately familiar with)? This matters, as it allows us to draw parallels for explaining and possibly better understand the reason underlying your problem.

Comment: @infinitezero: Listening to audio files does not help you if your ears are not trained for this difference at all. The phonetic alphabet may help to some extent to know what to pay attention to when pronouncing the sound yourself, but even then it has a very steep learning curve.

Comment: Ich häte eher Vewechselungsgefahr zwischen "e" und "ä" erwartet - trotz des Minimalpaares "Lerche" / "Lärche" (hier allerdings kurz statt wie bei den Buchstabennamen lang)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Der Buchstabe *i* wird wie der korrespondierende Langvokal [iː] ausgesprochen, *e* entsprechend als [eː].

Der Unterschied zwischen den beiden Lauten liegt im Grad der Offenheit: [iː] ist geschlossener als [eː], was bedeutet, daß sich die Zunge bei der Produktion von [iː] näher am Gaumen befindet als bei der von [eː].

Verschiedene Zungenstellungen führen zu unterschiedlichen Resonanzen im Vokaltrakt, die man *Formanten* nennt. Die Laute [iː] und [eː] werde in erster Linie durch den ersten Formanten F1 unterschieden, der bei [iː] niedriger ist als bei [eː]. In meinem Fall liegt F1 für [iː] bei um die 230 Hz, für [eː] bei um die 300 Hz. Diese Unterschiede werden auch in [Formantkarten des deutschen Vokalsystems](https://www.kw.tu-berlin.de/fileadmin/a01311100/Formantkarten_des_deutschen_Vokalsystems_01.pdf) deutlich.

Wenn die Muttersprache diesen Unterschied nicht kennt, wird man Schwierigkeiten haben, die Vokale akustisch zu differenzieren. Ein Minimalpaar wären die ersten Silben von [*Igel*](https://contribute.dict.cc/?action=audio-history&f=id-641454) – [*Egel*](https://contribute.dict.cc/?action=audio-history&f=id-374885).

Hintergrundinformationen, insbesondere auch zu Formanten, findet man auf der englischen [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vowel).

*Postscriptum.* Google Translate spricht [i e](https://translate.google.de/#view=home&op=translate&sl=de&tl=en&text=i%20e) so aus: *i* F1 ~ 330 Hz, F2 ~ 2750 Hz und *e* F1 ~ 430 Hz, F2 ~ 2600 Hz.

Comment: Danke. Würdest du als Fazit sagen, dass einem Muttersprachler der Unterschied immer ganz deutlich ist? Z.B., kommt jemand zu dir und ganz monoton und nicht besonders laut sagt "Der Zutritt ist vom Bahnsteig E2" - verstehst su sofort dass 'E' und nicht 'I' gemeint ist?

Comment: @sermonionx Die Vokale sind unterschiedlich genug, daß man sie grundsätzlich unterscheiden kann. Die Formantenkarten zeigen das auch.

Comment: @DavidVogt, naja, auf der Karte überlappen die beiden Vokale. Daher könnte man vermuten, dass man manchmal nicht genau sagen kann, um welchen es sich handelt, wenn man den Sprecher vorher nicht anderes sagen gehört hat.

Comment: @CarstenS Ich denke, das stimmt zwar, ist aber insofern irrelevant, als der Fragesteller den deutlichen Unterschied bei [Google Translate](https://translate.google.de/#view=home&op=translate&sl=de&tl=en&text=i%20e) nicht hören kann.