# Pronunciation of “Schnee”

Tags: pronunciation

I am trying to learn German and struggling with some aspects of pronunciation.

I have heard the word "Schnee" pronounced [here](https://forvo.com/word/schnee/#de) and elsewhere, and it sounds to me like it's pronounced /ʃniː/. However, the transcriptions I have seen change the vowel, making it /ʃneː/. Also, I have been told that the second way is correct. Am I simply hearing the vowel wrong? Does this differ by dialect? Is it something else?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problem differentiating between \[i:\] and \[e:\]](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/20035/problem-differentiating-between-i-and-e) Also https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/31580/pronunciation-of-long-e and https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/58632/wie-kann-man-zwischen-den-namen-der-buchstaben-i-und-e-unterscheiden

Comment: In the examples you've linked, the people pronounce it correctly as /ʃneː/. There is no dialect or anything. I'm afraid, you're hearing it wrong. Does your native language differentiate between both sounds?

Comment: It is worth saying that the voices of the various speakers (hermanthegerman, firmian, SophieSprache, fona, Thonatas, DagmarB) of the various speakers are *distinguishable*.  The question is then whether, to a native speaker, the voices are saying the same thing. The answer appears, from other comments, to be "yes", they are saying the same thing, indicating that to a native speaker, there is ***no phonemic distinction*** between the vowel produced by SophieSprache (and closely followed by DagmarB) and the vowel produced by Thonatas.  Continued in the next comment ...

Comment: I hear the vowels as being ***extremely different*** because they represent two phonemically distinct sounds in my language. However, you just have to accept that a native speaker hears them as being  (in terms of meaning), the same. So you can speak like Thonatas, or like SophieSprache, and a native German speaker will apparently not hear any important difference in what you are saying. I think it was a great pity that your question was close off! The answer that was referenced in the comments is actually the exact OPPOSITE of your problem. Continued ...

Comment: The person who posted the question in https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/20035/problem-differentiating-between-i-and-e was incapable of distinguishing the two sounds. The problem that you and I have is that the sounds produced, for example, by Thonatas and SophieSprache, sound radically different ... and we have to train ourselves to accept them as actually being phonemically identical!

Comment: Yes, some of those <e>s are really more centralized (almost Schwa-like), others more raised. But that's indeed no phonological contrast. What is your native language, if I may ask?