# Warum das 'e' manchmal wie 'i' klingt

Tags: word-usage, pronunciation, phonetics, vowel

Wenn ein Wort zwei "e" in Silben zusammen hat, wird das erste oft "i",

B.s: verstehen = vastihen ausgesprochen.

Warum? Ist es der Beginn der Trennung der Buchstaben- und Vokallaute (ähnlich wie im Englischen)?

-Meine Muttersprache ist Spanisch: wir haben nur 5 vokale-

Comment: TBH, I cannot follow or agree to the conjecture the question is based upon, including the example. As such I cannot see how this question can be answered. Also see and listen to https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/verstehen

Comment: If your native language doesn't have this distinction, you will have trouble making it. See also https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/20035/problem-differentiating-between-i-and-e https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7872/what-is-the-difference-in-pronunciation-of-the-letters-e-and-i.

Comment: Compare that sound with the similar word 'verstiegen' (past of versteigen): https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/verstiegen

Comment: I do not think that the “stehen” in “verstehen” is pronounced any differently from “stehen” alone.

Comment: Das lange e in einem Wort wie st**e**hen wird halbgeschlossen ausgesprochen (im Gegensatz zum kurzen e) und ist daher lautlich relativ nahe am i. Für einen Nichtmuttersprachler kann es daher schwer sein, es von einem i zu unterscheiden. Trotzdem handelt es sich um einen anderen Laut.

Comment: @planetmaker: Schreibe Kommentare bitte immer in derselben Sprache in der auch die Frage formuliert wurde. Du weißt nur, dass die Fragestellerin Deutsch und Spanisch spricht. Du hast aber keine Information über ihre Englisch-Kentnisse. Daher solltest du auch keine englischen Kommentare unter deutsche Fragen stellen.

Comment: @DavidVogt: Für dich gilt ebenfalls, was ich in dem an planetmaker gerichteten Kommentar geschrieben habe.

Comment: @CarstenS: Für dich gilt ebenfalls, was ich in dem an planetmaker gerichteten Kommentar geschrieben habe.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast, denkst Du, mir ist das nicht eigentlich klar? Kannst Du Dir vorstellen, dass es passiert, dass man das nicht merkt, insbesondere, wenn schon einige Kommentare auf Englisch dastehen?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Das tut es nicht -- zumindest in keinem mir bekannten Dialekt.

Allerdings handelt es hier nicht um zwei gleiche "e".  Dem Muttersprachler meist unbekannt, hat das Deutsche, seinen fünf (oder acht) Buchtstaben für Vokale gegenüberstehend, ca. 15 verschiedene [vokalische Phoneme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_German_phonology#Vowels).  Unter anderem zwei, die oft dem geschriebenen <e> entsprechen, nämlich das lange /eː/ (*l**e**gen*) und das kurze /ɛ/ (*l**e**cken*).  Generell kommen die meisten Vokale in lang/kurz-Paaren vor, unterscheiden sich aber alle auch in der Qualität (in der dt. Sprachwissenschaft ist dafür der Begriff "Gespanntheit" gebräuchlich).

Dazu kommen in vielen reduzierten Kontexten noch besonders reduzierte Vokale, sogenannte Schwas: /ə/ (*lieg**e***) und /ɐ/.  Letzteres ergibt sich in den meisten Fällen nicht aus <a>, sondern aus unbetontem <-er>: *leid**er***.

Zurück zu deinem Beispiel: *verstehen* wird meist etwa als [fɐʃteːn] ausgesprochen -- wahrscheinlich ist das der von dir bemerkte Unterschied.  Oder, bei bemüht deutlicher Aussprache, [fəɐʃteːn] oder [fərʃteːən].  Hier ist nirgends etwas <i>-artiges.

Allerdings liegt das Schwa /ə/, per definitionem ein komplett entspannter Mittelvokal, ziemlich am Mittelwert aller Vokale, was je nach Prägung des Hörers (zB. durch das Phoneminventar einer nicht-deutschen Erstsprache) dazu führen kann, dass es als unterschiedliche andere Laute fehlinterpretiert wird.

Wenn man sich sonst das [deutsche Vokaltrapez](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Northern_Standard_German_vowel_chart.svg) so anschaut, könnte es noch sein, dass du die Nähe vom /eː/ zum /ɪ/ (*Z**i**nn*) übergeneralisierst; jedenfalls gibt es im Spanischen, wenn ich richtig verstehe, dort nur ein /e/ etwa in der Mitte eines ganzen Haufens deutscher Phoneme:

[image: Deutsches Vokaltrapez]

Außerdem kommt es natürlich stark auf den Sprecher an, wie sehr die Vokale differenziert werden.  Ein Schweizer würde vermutlich eher sowas wie [fərʃtɛːn]; ein Steirer [fɐʃteɪn].  Je weiter im Südösten man ist, desto mehr nähern sich /e/ und /ɛ/ an.  Vokale sind selbst standardsprachlich recht fluid.

Comment: +1 This answer is a good example how to answer the question behind the question

Comment: Man könnte hinzufügen, dass für einige Sprecher anderer Sprachen das lange e und i schwer zu unterscheiden sind. Das scheint hier auch hineinzuspielen, und wir hatten schon einige Fragen dazu, siehe Davids Kommentar zur Frage.

Comment: Ja, das habe ich mit der "Prägung des Hörers" gemeint.

Comment: Das habe ich so verstanden, dass es sich auf das dritte e in „verstehen“ bezieht. Ich hatte die Frage so interpretiert, dass sie sich auf das zweite e bezieht. Jedenfalls deutete „vastihen“ darauf hin. Ich finde die Frage allerdings auch nicht besonders klar.

Comment: @CarstenS Ups, stimmt. Die Verwechslung hab ich wohl einfach ausgeblendet, weil sie mir unwahrscheinlich vorgekommen ist. Aber mit dem Vokaltrapez vor Augen macht es mehr Sinn.

Comment: Ich danke Ihnen vielmals.  Das Schwa und das Vokaltrapez - für mich neue Begriffe - waren der Schlüssel zum Verständnis. Damit habe ich zusätzliche Informationen auf Spanisch gefunden (das einen konstanten Rhythmus hat, so dass Klang und Symbol immer übereinstimmen). https://www.wikiwand.com/es/Fonolog%C3%ADa_del_alem%C3%A1n

Comment: Und was das deutsche Schwa angeht, war dieses Video auch sehr nützlich: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l4lelPvqN7M